# How to declare child's type in parent class?

Tags: types, dart

Dart code:

```
main() {
    var child1 = new Child1();
    var t = child1.childType();
}

class Parent {
    ??? childType() {
        return this.runtimeType;
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
}
```

You can see the `???` in class `Parent`, I want it to reference to child's type, but I don' know how to declare it.

In scala, it can be:

```
def childType(): this.type = {
    ...
}
```

But I don't know how to do it in dart. Is it possible? If not possible, what's the best type to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need the return type of `childType` to statically be declared as the right subtype, you can use generics:

```dart
class Parent<C extends Parent> {
  C get childType => runtimeType;
}

class Child1 extends Parent<Child1> {}

class Child2 extends Parent<Child2> {}
```

I'd really make sure you need that though. You could just keep `childType` typed as `Parent`.